# Start bundle executable on bootup (Mac OSX/)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, bundler, sidekiq

I'm trying to setup a Mac OSX system as a server, and would like my rails application to start at bootup, including all dependent applications. I've managed to get passenger/nginx and redis to start, but am having trouble with starting sidekiq.

More specifically, I would like to run this command at startup `bundle exec sidekiq -q carrierwave -e production -P /path/to/pid_file`.

I've tried creating the following plist file and adding it to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Debug</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.sidekiq</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle</string>
    <string>exec</string>
    <string>sidekiq</string>
    <string>-q</string>
    <string>carrierwave</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>production</string>
    <string>-P</string>
    <string>/path/to/sidekiq.pid</string>
  </array>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>RAILS_ENV</key>
    <string>production</string>
  </dict>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/path/to/rails/project</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/path/to/log/sidekiq.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/path/to/log/sidekiq_err.log</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I run `sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/my.sidekqi.plist` to load and start the daemon, but the system console shows an exit code 127 for this launchd (and repeatedly tries to restart).

If I run the program arguments from the command line, I get a "Gemfile not found" error (assuming I'm not in the rails project dir). If I run from the project dir, sidekiq will start. From what I understand, WorkingDirectoy should execute the bundle command within the specified path (which is my rails project path).

I believe the problem stems from bundle not being executed within the rails project directory. So either I need to get launchd to start the process in the working directory (which isn't working for some reason) or execute the bundle command outside of the project directory but somehow instructing it where the gem file resides.

I'm also using rvm, if this matters. ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.13, mac osx lion.

Thanks

Comment: May be you should specify path to bundle executable instead of bundle itself? Something like `/Users/path/to/bundle/Contents/MacOS/executable` as a first program argument

Comment: Sorry if that is unclear. I am pointing to the executable, which is more like /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle. This is my output when I run `which bundle`

Comment: exit code 127 is not a lot of information. You might want to check the console (Console.app in the Utilities folder - Cmd-U in the Finder) and see if there's a more descriptive error message there that might point you in the right direction.  Also, I notice you don't have an element in the plist to say what account this should run as. I don't know for sure, but it wouldn't surprise me if that was related to your problem.

Comment: This is part of my problem, the console doesn't reveal anymore information. From what I understand, the user account is optional (it will run as root as default). I did notice that the sidekiq_err file contains: `env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory`

Comment: I encounter the same problem. I google and come here, but no answer help me.

Comment: I never figured this one out. Sorry. Hope this makes you feel better: http://xkcd.com/979/